# transform.position teleporting. Not smoothly moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Simple question but hard time finding an answer.

I have a hook mechanic where on the press of key.B, a hook will fire for 5 seconds then should come back.

This code is working fine, just that when the code allocated to recall the object, it does not comeback smoothly, it teleports.
Here is the code, the problem-specific line in **BOLD**

```
public class Hook : MonoBehaviour
{ //Remember Couroutine is pretty much update()

public Transform Target;
private float Thrust; // Int for motion
public Rigidbody rb;
public float HookTravelTime; //Define float for seconds
bool isHookActive = false;  //Are we currently moving?
public float timeHookTraveling = 0f;




// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    Thrust = 75f;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    float walkspeed = Thrust * Time.deltaTime;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "mob")
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        print("Other code negated");
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.position, Thrust);
        isHookActive = false;
        timeHookTraveling = 0f;
    }
}


void ThrowHook()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
    {
        isHookActive = true;
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Thrust);
    }
    if (isHookActive )
        {
            if (timeHookTraveling >= HookTravelTime) //if the hook traveled for more than hookTravelTime(5 seconds in your case)
            {

            print("hehemeth");
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero; //negate addforce from before
          **HERE**  transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.position, Thrust);
            isHookActive = false;//reset this bool so your Update will not check this script until you don't activate it in your ThrowHook
            timeHookTraveling = 0f;//reset the travel time for your next hook activation
        }

            else//if you havent hit 5 keep increasing
            {
                timeHookTraveling += Time.deltaTime;//increase your travel time by last frame's time
            }
        }
    }



// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
    {
    ThrowHook();
    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong? It should work as intended, right?

Comment: Two things, 1. where do you invoke the `ThrowHook()`? 2. how do you define `Thrust`, what value?

Comment: Just edited in the rest of the code

Comment: Try this `transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.position, Thrust * Time.deltaTime);`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, It just teleports back a short distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector3.MoveTowards is needed to be run everyframe, that's why I mentioned `* Time.deltaTime` in comment.

At 5s, rb's velocity becomes zero and `isHookActive` becomes false, and thus `Vector3.MoveTowards` is not called everyframe.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
{
    isHookActive = true;
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Thrust);
}
if (isHookActive )
{
    if (timeHookTraveling >= HookTravelTime) //if the hook traveled for more than hookTravelTime(5 seconds in your case)
    {

        print("hehemeth");
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero; //negate addforce from before
        isHookActive = false;//reset this bool so your Update will not check this script until you don't activate it in your ThrowHook
        timeHookTraveling = 0f;//reset the travel time for your next hook activation
    }

    else//if you havent hit 5 keep increasing
    {
        timeHookTraveling += Time.deltaTime;//increase your travel time by last frame's time
    }
}

else if (!isHookActive && transform.position != Target.position)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target.position, Thrust * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

And a even better way is putting

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
{
    isHookActive = true;
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Thrust);
}
```

into `FixedUpdate()` but not `Update()` while

```
if (isHookActive )
{... }
```

remains in `Update()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally got what was going wrong thanks to you! Never thought that my code would stop being called at all!